# Magento admin Store Email Addresses Email id not set

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, email, admin-panel

I have domain with **.XYZ** extension means `test@abc.xyz`.

I had tried to set ID in to

```
ADMIN -> System -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
```

Not set it and Fire a ERROR :

> Invalid email address **test@abc.xyz**.

So who to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get an error when validating that email address in 1.9.x, you could try a local override of the following Model:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/backend/Email/Address.php
```

from

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    $value = $this->getValue();
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($value, 'EmailAddress')) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid email address "%s".', $value));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

To

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    $value = $this->getValue();
    /*if (!Zend_Validate::is($value, 'EmailAddress')) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid email address "%s".', $value));
    }*/
    return $this;
}
```

This is bypasses validation process. So you cant get this errro for any domain.

Comment: if i comment this code, it is effect on  admin configuration file so when i put TEST@TEST.COM wrong email id so not given me any error.Give me batter way to fixed it.